# Colorbox in IE - loading external page, tries to download content, not play

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

Simple project: http://mannyllerena.com/

When you are in IE and click on "Live Interviews" it prompts you to download the media rather than allowing it to play from the called URL...

More of a designer than coder. Need some help!

And here is JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
        $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example2']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example3']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example4']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example7']").colorbox();
        $(".example7").colorbox({width:"40%", height:"25%", iframe:true});

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
            $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And here is HTML:

```
<a class="projects example7" href="http://www.floordaily.net/UploadedFiles/RadioInterviews/MP3/Manny_2-15-08.mp3"  title=" " rel="example7">Live<br />Interviews</a>
<a class="example7" href="http://www.floordaily.net/UploadedFiles/RadioInterviews/MP3/Manny%20from%20Mohawk%27s%20Floorscapes%20meeting%20in%202008.mp3"  title=" " rel="example7"></a>
<a class="example7" href="http://www.floordaily.net/UploadedFiles/RadioInterviews/MP3/Manny%20Llerena%20Discusses%20the%20Highlights%20of%20Mohawks%20Aligned%20Retailer%20Meeting.mp3"  title=" " rel="example7"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is not with the colorbox in IE, but rather how IE handles video and audio files.  It will also be dependant on how each person has their IE set up.  Normally a browser will have something built-in to play music and video files.  Microsoft, however, assumes that you would be much happier using another of their products and opens media player.

To prevent this, you will need to embed your music or video files into a prebuilt player.  Yahoo offers a pretty easy solution that's all done in javascript - or rather, everything you do with the player is in javascript.  Here are the steps you'll need to take to integrate that into colorbox:

1) Set up a seperate page with all the code for the player.  Here goes:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Click blocker test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var YWPParams = {
        autoplay:true,
        volume:0.5
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.yahooapis.com/player-beta.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="font-size:200%">
    <a id="test1" href="http://www.floordaily.net/UploadedFiles/RadioInterviews/MP3/Manny_2-15-08.mp3" style="display:none">Video</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

2) Then in the page with the link to your mp3 file:

```
$("#playerLink").colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    width:"50%",
    height:"50%" //or whatever dimensions you like
});
```

Basically the way it works (with these settings) is that the Yahoo script searches for any links with an `.mp3` extension and loads them into the player. More info on the settings for Yahoo's player can be found [here](http://webplayer.yahoo.com/).

This is just an example of one player, there's a bunch out there.  There's a [jquery mp3 player here](http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/), but just searching for embedded mp3 players will give you plenty of results.